# The "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths

Tags: gulp, pug, gulp-wrap

I am new to the *gulp* frameworks. I have been working on a small *gulp* script, which will pipe a Markdown file to a JSON string, then use a *Jade* template to render the final HTML. I am using `gulp-wrap` to pass the data into my jade template

```
// md to jade blog
gulp.task('blog', () => {
  gulp.src(path.join(dirs.source, dirs.blogs, entries.md))
    .pipe(md(marked))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(wrap(function(data) {
    // read correct jade template from disk
    let template = path.join(dirs.source, dirs.layouts, data.contents.template)
    // template location is at 'src/_layouts/base-blog.jade'
    return fs.readFileSync(template).toString();
    }, {

    }, {
      engine: 'jade'
    }))
    .pipe(rename({extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
}
```

I keep getting the following error when I run it:

```
 Message:
Jade:11
9|   //- var pageTitle = config.pageTitle || ''
10|
> 11| include ../_modules/project-list/project-list
12| include ../_modules/about/about
13|
14| doctype html

the "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths
Details:
path: undefined
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear here:

> the "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths

So:

- either find a way to pass the "filename" option to your Jade/Pug command, by using `-p`

  ```
  > pug --help
  [...]
      -p, --path <path>      filename used to resolve includes
  ```
- or make your file paths absolute

Comment: Thanks @Filaton,

          .pipe(wrap(function(data) {
      // read correct jade template from disk
      let template = path.join(dirs.source, dirs.layouts, data.contents.template)
      return fs.readFileSync(template).toString();
      }, {
        pretty: true,
        filename: path.join(dirs.source, dirs.layouts, 'base-blog.jade'),
        basedir: path.resolve(),
        config: config
      },
I got that fixed by asign the layout names. But it is pretty much try and error to find out where I should put the code in gulp-wrap

Comment: Yup, I agree that the documentation on Jade/Pug/Gulp could be better, but glad you solved it. Welcome on Stack Overflow! :)